# Excel Dynamic Function Selection

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to run a function based on the datatype of a value.

I'm able to identify if a value is a number or a letter.

[image]

Here is my formula for column 3...

```
="="&IF(A2=TRUE, "value(", "upper(")&B2&")"
```

How could I get excel to invoke my function? Right now it is just displaying the text and not running the function.

Thank You

Comment: `=if(isnumber(a1),value(a1),upper(a1))` You are just entering a string into the cell which is not recognised as a formula.

Comment: Thank you. I can’t believe I couldn’t figure this out myself.

Comment: Can you add a question so I can mark it as correct? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to build a string to represent a formula, which won't work, so the simpler solution is just:

```
=if(isnumber(a1),value(a1),upper(a1))
```